# Reduce Tibco EMS memory usage

Tags: java, tibco, tibco-ems

On my developer machine I need to start Tibco EMS server to develop application which require it running.
But I don't really need it in high performance state.
How could I configure Tibco to use system resources as low as possible?

Thanks.

Comment: I would ask Tibco using your support as this is a commercial product, or I would ask a tibco forum.  I don't believe there is anything you can do using Java to change this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can control a number of memory parameters such as `max_msg_memory` and `reserve_memory` via the `tibemsd.conf` file. Please see the [TIBCO Enterprise Message Service™ Documentation](https://docs.tibco.com/products/tibco-enterprise-message-service-6-1) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Would it be possible for you to set up the EMS server on a different machine that would be running only the EMS?

Answer (score 0):

If delete datafiles from `config/tibco/cfgmgmt/ems/data/datastore/`tibco will not restore state at startup.
Wrote simple .cmd to delete data files and start tibco.
Startup time increased dramatically.